# Angular 2 template form validation not working

Tags: angular, validation

I am working on an example of Angular 2 template template driven forms and started with basic validation and it does not work.

I checked the systex from the video tutorial that I am referring and I have done exactly the same thing that has been shown in video.

The issue is when I hit Submit/OK button, it does not give any validation error message. I am also attaching the error message that appears in the tutorial video.

**Code Sample 1:**

HTML file of component:

```
<form #form="ngForm" > 

    <input 
      type="text"
      id="name"
      required 
      placeholder="Name" 
      name="name" 
      ngModel>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>

</form>
```

TS File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    // Do stuff
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Hello About');
  }

}
```

I also tried by adding **form-control** tags, but it also didn't worked

**Code Sample 2:**

Modified HTML file of the above mentioned component:

```
<form #form="ngForm" > 

  <div class="form-group">
    <input 
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      id="name"
      required 
      placeholder="Name" 
      name="name" 
      ngModel>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but only with the help of user's :- **@yurzui** comments.

This is not issue but rather behavior of Angular 4 that I am using, that it by default adds **novalidate** to the form.

I verified it by **not** adding using the **novalidate** to the form and adding required tag to my input control and in the end I added **{{ form.valid }}**.

The valid is true only if I entered any value in my input control.

That proved that my control was following the **required** tag but the form's default and invisible **novalidate** was hindering it to show any error message by default.

```
<form #form="ngForm" >

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstNameId" class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <input #firstName="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameId" required placeholder="Name" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName">
  </div>


  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button>

</form>

{{ form.valid }}
```